# Handling typesetting of plural class names

Tags: best-practices, typewriter

I'm sorry if this is the wrong stackexchange to ask in, but it seems to be the place where people care about typography :)

I'm writing lecture notes on Android development, and I like to put class names and code fragments in monospaced in order to make it easier to read.

For instance `\texttt{Activity}` is used a lot.

My question is how should I typeset the plural reference?

`\texttt{Activity}s` looks wrong

`activities` doesn't distinguish from other text

`\texttt{Activities}` removes the verbatim nature that I'm trying to convey using the texttt.

Any recommendations and guidelines will be appreciated.

Comment: I have a feeling you can use `\texttt{Activity}(s)` or declare at the beginning that `...hereon now known as \texttt{activity} regardless if is considered just one or many.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I think I like the \textt{Activity}(s) most, then I just need to make sure I'm consistent, but that is not going to go away.

Comment: For future reference, you might find [English Language and Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/) to be another suitable forum for such questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you should rewrite to avoid plurals. For instance, don't write `"Activities are used for..."`, but write `"Activity objects are used for..."` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this will probably give the cleanest look throughout the text.

Answer (score 3):

If you write a macro that encapsulates the format you can change the format consistently at will. Here's an implementation that follows @JohnWickerson 's excellent suggestion.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\class}[1]{%
\texttt{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\class{Activity} objects capture \ldots

\end{document}
```

Comment: That doesn't actually allow changing the format at will. If the questioner wants to do that they should define both `\activity` and `\activities`, which they can then set as appropriate.

Comment: @dbmag This does let the OP change the typography _simultaneously_ for all words defining a `\class` . I agree with another comment that the class names shouldn't have plural versions, since they are part of compilable code the OP is describing.

Comment: It's a good way of doing what others have said, yes. But your answer suggests it's a way to choose between different answers to the question (ie different conventions on how to pluralise the class name), which is isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my previous comment, and inspired by the other two answers, this is my approach:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\actone}{\texttt{Activity}(s)}
\newcommand{\acttwo}{\texttt{Activity}(-ies)}

\begin{document}

In the next \actone{} you'll see\ldots{}

In the next \acttwo{} you'll see\ldots{}

\end{document}
```

[image]